# Is this is a correct backpropagation implementation?

Tags: backpropagation, gradient-descent

Is this is a correct implementation for backpropagation?
The network has three layers and the activation function is relu.

```
def back_propagation(error, learning_rate, layer, wights, bias):
    for i0 in range(len(layer)):
        for i1 in range(len(layer[0])):
            wights[i0][i1] = wights[i0][i1] - (learning_rate * ((layer[i0][i1] / wights[i0][i1]) * (error / layer[i0][i1])))
            bias = bias - (learning_rate * ((layer[i0][i1] / bias) * (error / layer[i0][i1])))
```